# How to add reclick in dropdown JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm creating my first script with JQuery and for test me with the basics I'm trying to do an easy menu dropdown in JQuery. The code work perfectly, but there's a problem, I would that if I reclick on button for open a text If the text is open If reclick this should be close, here the code:

```js
$( ".select1" ).click(function() {
  $(".content1").css("display", "block"); 
});

$( ".select2").click(function() {
  $(".content2").css("display", "block");                   
})

$(".select3").click(function() {
  $(".content3").css("display", "block");
})

$(".select4").click(function() {
  $(".content4").css("display", "block");
})
```

```css
article {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
  <p class="select1">Select 1</p>
  <article class="content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae mollitia aliquid quas doloremque, repudiandae vel odio nisi repellendus accusantium temporibus distinctio labore, debitis tenetur, in assumenda. Odio possimus pariatur, vitae!</article>
  <p class="select2">Select 2</p>
  <article class="content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas iure, doloribus qui quasi est, quo obcaecati modi ab nesciunt pariatur a id rerum reprehenderit, beatae corrupti consequatur ut placeat ipsa!</article>
  <p class="select3">Select 3</p>
  <article class="content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque voluptate beatae placeat nobis porro, id ipsum. Incidunt minima deserunt, delectus. Ad unde obcaecati natus quo excepturi, tempore consectetur odio explicabo.</article>
  <p class="select4">Select 4</p>
  <article class="content4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil praesentium ex ipsa dolor alias ratione repellat eos? Eveniet architecto officiis, veniam reiciendis animi, enim aperiam error dignissimos expedita laborum eius.</article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show and hide element using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). I've chosen `.toggleClass()`, since it's easier to start in a hidden state:

```js
/** You need only one declaration using a common selector - class .select in this case **/
$( ".select" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('visibile'); // if clicked toggle the class on the next element (the article)
});
```

```css
article:not(.visibile) { /** all articles that don't have the class visible, should be hidden **/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
  <p class="select">Select 1</p>
  <article class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae mollitia aliquid quas doloremque, repudiandae vel odio nisi repellendus accusantium temporibus distinctio labore, debitis tenetur, in assumenda. Odio possimus pariatur, vitae!</article>
  <p class="select">Select 2</p>
  <article class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas iure, doloribus qui quasi est, quo obcaecati modi ab nesciunt pariatur a id rerum reprehenderit, beatae corrupti consequatur ut placeat ipsa!</article>
  <p class="select">Select 3</p>
  <article class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque voluptate beatae placeat nobis porro, id ipsum. Incidunt minima deserunt, delectus. Ad unde obcaecati natus quo excepturi, tempore consectetur odio explicabo.</article>
  <p class="select">Select 4</p>
  <article class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil praesentium ex ipsa dolor alias ratione repellat eos? Eveniet architecto officiis, veniam reiciendis animi, enim aperiam error dignissimos expedita laborum eius.</article>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your code. You can do this with `slideToggle()` to show/hide the `next()` article.

```
$("p" ).click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
});
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/brf03f9g/1/)